# Launching Google Form as Web App using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

How do I launch a google form as a web app using google App Script? I have this piece of test code but get the message "The script completed but did not return anything."

```
function doGet() 
{
  // Create and open a form.
  var form = FormApp.create('Form');

  var item = form.addCheckboxItem();
  item.setTitle('What condiments would you like on your hot dog?')
     .setChoices([
           item.createChoice('Ketchup'),
           item.createChoice('Mustard'),
           item.createChoice('Relish')
     ])

  return form; 
}
```

Comment: Your code runs very well on my end. I think you need to create a new version of your project for "Script as Web App" since updating the previous version did not update its sharing settings. See: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1rJ2PqVprimek1xHzjgxv2GZ4q8ZoFxQIr3dXBtc5nxg/viewform?usp=send_form

Answer (score 0):

You can

> create, access, and modify Google Forms

with **Forms Service**.

But you can not open up a Form without using the Form's published URL.  An Apps Script URL is different than a Forms URL.  A Forms URL looks like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/FormID/viewform
```

The Apps Script URL is like this:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/
```

If you trigger and run that script from some type of HTML, and then get the Form URL back to the HTML App, then you could create the form with code, and then launch it.  The HTML App needs to be able to launch a new browser tab (or window).  You can't launch the new form from server side `gs` code.  The `doGet()` won't work for launching the new Form.

Comment: Can you show me example code of how the gs file and the html file would work together?

Comment: The one and only way that HTML can call a `.gs` server script is with `gooogle.script.run`.  Start here:  [Google Documentation - Google Script Run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function))  When your script that creates the form is done, it needs to get the published URL of the Form, and return it.  The returned Form URL value will be handled by the `withSuccessHandler` function.  That function needs to do something, like put the URL into a link tag, or run a `window.open()` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is a test script for creating a form.  I am sure after you deployed and run it a new form was created on your drive and did what it's supposed to do, just load the newly created form link.

If you'd like to display something on your browser you need to use HTML Service.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

```
function doGet() 
{
  // Create and open a form.
  var form = FormApp.create('Form');

  var item = form.addCheckboxItem();
  item.setTitle('What condiments would you like on your hot dog?')
     .setChoices([
       item.createChoice('Ketchup'),
       item.createChoice('Mustard'),
       item.createChoice('Relish')
 ])

 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Success you created a new form!"); 
}
```

Another way to launch a form as a web app is to use the HTML service and you can create your own customized form.  You will have an idea how this will be done on this link.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

And here's a link to read about web apps https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.